# parameterize Connect.Sys property in Test complete

Tags: c#, ui-automation, testcomplete

Trying to get text out of an application using test complete. But in the object expression the Text is hard coded. How to parametarize it.

code:

var t = Connect.Sys.Process("CallingCard").Window("#32770", "DXC Remote Rescue Calling Card", 1).Window("#32770", "", 3).Window("Button", "Continue", 2);

String s = t["wText"];

Here , from continue button i am trying to get the text which is "Continue".
But how to parametarize "Continue" if i want to pass it as variable .

Answer (score 0):

You can have variable like var btnText

var btnText = "Continue";
var t = Connect.Sys.Process("CallingCard").Window("#32770", "DXC Remote Rescue Calling Card", 1).Window("#32770", "", 3).Window("Button", btnText, 2);

String s = t["wText"];

Or Use FindChild method and pass btnText as parameter to find the button object